# Does any Scripture say women who are suffering period are untouchable by men or they cant go temple

Tags: belief

Could anyone tell me about why womens are kept untouchable when they are in period.In which scripture it is mentioned.And any scientific explanation of it?
Because nowadays girls are becoming extra secular and liberal we have to explain them about that..

Comment: What do you mean with "untouchable"? I don't believe there is a traditional term for "untouchable" found in any Sanskrit manuscript.

Comment: No.I mean Does Any scripture says womens when they are suffering period are untouchable...

Comment: I think many  in Hindu people follows this tradition...

Comment: Again, what do you mean with the term "untouchable"? Do you refer to the modern concept of "untouchability", or are you looking for a Sanskrit word literally translating to "untouchable"?

Comment: @GabeHiemstra The woman is literally untouchable - as in must not come in contact with other people, food, water, cloth etc. used by others. She isolates herself.

Comment: There is the instance of Draupadi's vastrapaharana where she is "ekavastra" meaning, she is menstruating and warns Dussasana that she must not come into court in her condition. I have heard that the Yajur veda has mandates on menstruation protocols. Parasara smriti lists these protocols as well. So you have sruti, smriti and itihaasa saying that women are "untouchable" during the time.